# Error message. "Props with type Object/Array must use a factory function to return the default value."

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am using Vue-Cli3.0. I used this module for Vue.js. https://github.com/holiber/sl-vue-tree

This is a customizable draggable tree component for Vue.js but I found that it could not copy functions of object.

https://github.com/holiber/sl-vue-tree/blob/master/src/sl-vue-tree.js#L715

Because of here.

```
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(entity))
```

So I used this module and edited the copy function.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/clone

```
var clone = require('clone');

copy(entity) {
    return clone(entity)
},
```

In this way, the function of the object is correctly copied.

I already have tested it, and it worked correctly. There was no problem with the performance but I got a console error.

```
[Vue warn]: Invalid default value for prop "multiselectKey": Props with type Object/Array must use a factory function to return the default value.

found in

---> <SlVueTree>
```

I want to know the way to erase this error.
Thank you for reading my question.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

according to your console warn, i find the error

https://github.com/holiber/sl-vue-tree/blob/master/src/sl-vue-tree.js#L30

try to fix it like this:

```
multiselectKey: {
  type: [String, Array],
  default: function () {
    return ['ctrlKey', 'metaKey']
  },
  validator: function (value) {
    let allowedKeys = ['ctrlKey', 'metaKey', 'altKey'];
    let multiselectKeys = Array.isArray(value) ? value : [value];
    multiselectKeys = multiselectKeys.filter(keyName => allowedKeys.indexOf(keyName ) !== -1);
    return !!multiselectKeys.length;
  }
},
```

the component default value must use a factory function to return!

try it and hope it can help you

Comment: Oh my gosh. You are a genius.I tried this , and it was deep copied correctly with no console error.Thank you so much!!!!!

Comment: Console error was erased! But I now found out that I forgot to write very important thing. I forgot to write that even with console error , there was no problem in performance. Even with console error message , it was deep copied correctly and it worked properly. But I just wanted to erase the console error.

Answer (score 149):

A factory function in props looks like this:

```
props: {
    exampleDefaultObject: {
        type: Object,
        default() {
            return {}
        }
    },
    exampleDefaultArray: {
        type: Array,
        default() {
            return []
        }
    }
},
```

or in ES6:

```
props: {
    exampleDefaultObject: {
        type: Object,
        default: () => ({})
    },
    exampleDefaultArray: {
        type: Array,
        default: () => []
    }
},
```

(for people who come here looking for an explanation of the error in the question 'props with type object/array must use a factory function to return the default value')

Note that when returning an object in an es6 arrow function, you need the parentheses: `() => ({})` instead of `() => {}`

Comment: Thanks this is the answer I was looking for when searching this question

Comment: @KatinkaHesselink so factory functions in vue are needed for performance? Or why cant we just set the default to `[]` or `{}`? Thanks.

Comment: You can set the default to [] or {} when you define a component yourself. Most of the time that's fine. I would not recommend changing that to a factory function unless you find that you do have performance issues (and this reduces them). The original question was about a drag-and-drop component: that's one of the use-cases where performance will often be an issue and where using a factory function may reduce that problem.

Comment: @CodeConnoisseur I wondered that too. The documentation says "Object or array defaults must be returned from a factory function." - https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#props but they don't detail why. My guess is because like component `data()` it should return a new instance each time, else you could have problems with many components referencing the same array. I found ESLint complained when setting it to a [], and I'm glad now!

Answer (score 12):

these cases require a function than produce the default value, not an object or array:

```
obj_param:{
        type:Object,
        default:()=>({})
},
array_param:{
        type:Array,
        default:()=>[]
},
```

this is for performance reasons, since the function is called only if needed (no value so use default), while the direct value would be instantiated everytime the component is used

Answer (score 3):

In TS format in my class component I have used it similarly as follows. It solved my error.
Thanks to [Trick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8062794/trick) & [Katinka](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8007395/katinka-hesselink) for solution above!

```
@Prop({default(){return []}}) private markerList!: Array<markerType>;
```